# apply a jQuery function on a CkEditor

Tags: php, jquery, html, ckeditor

I have a `textarea` in my html file, and I need to send the data in the `textarea` to the database. However, the `textarea` send the data without the `enter` spaces. so a data like this:

```
Shortly after reading a few books on web design, I was hooked. I wanted to know everything and anything about it. I was designing websites any chance I could. 

I spent almost all of my savings buying more books on different programming languages and other nerdy computer gear.
```

would be like this in the database.

```
Shortly after reading a few books on web design, I was hooked. I wanted to know everything and anything about it. I was designing websites any chance I could. I spent almost all of my savings buying more books on different programming languages and other nerdy computer gear.
```

So I decided to change the textarea to a `ckeditor` to send the data as html. But the problem now that I have a `jQuery` method on the `textarea`, and now it won't work.

HTML :

```
<td>
<textarea maxlength="5000" id="blah" cols="100" rows="20" name="essay_content" class="ckeditor" onkeyup="words();">
</textarea></td>
```

jQuery:

```
function words(content)
{
    var f = $("#blah").val()
    $('#othman').load('wordcount.php?content='+ encodeURIComponent(f));


}
```

now it won't work with me because the text area is a CkEditor ... any suggestions ?

Comment: use [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) with textarea. do not use CK editor just for white space problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the contents of the CkEditor textarea:

```
function words(content)
{
    var f = CKEDITOR.instances.blah.getData();
    $('#othman').load('wordcount.php?content='+ encodeURIComponent(f));
}
```

But,I don't think the `onkeyup` will work, because CkEditor replaces the textarea. You would need to create a plugin for CkEditor to catch the key up trigger within the editor instance.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `nlbr` and everything works.